# fclose gives Uncaught TypeError: fclose(): Argument #1 ($stream) must be of type resource, string given in php8.1

Tags: php

I use the code below to read out a XML file on a remote server. It all worked in PHP7, but in PHP8.1 it gives a fatal error.

Uncaught TypeError: fclose(): Argument #1 ($stream) must be of type resource, string given in

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
$remoteFile='/in/'.$row['verificatie'].'_'.$bestandsnaam.'.xml';
$file = file_get_contents("ssh2.sftp://$sftp$remoteFile", 'w');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($file);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$response = json_decode($json);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/function.file-get-contents) returns a string, and does not keep a file pointer open. There's no need to use [`fclose()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) on it. -- `The file pointer must be valid, and must point to a file successfully opened by fopen() or fsockopen().`

Comment: Thanks! I removed it. Now everything works.